# Ghost doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, ghost.py

I'm trying to use the example code from his own website and it does not work at all:

```
from ghost import Ghost
ghost = Ghost()

page, resources = ghost.open('http://google.com')
```

It's a quite simple example and this is the traceback :

```
AttributeError: 'Ghost' object has no attribute 'open'
```

I'm working with Python 2.7, I have already installed PySide 1.2.4 for 64bits and I'm working in a machine with Windows7

EDIT:

I have tried this :

```
import ghost
g = ghost.Ghost()
with g.start() as session:
     page, extra_resources = session.open("http://www.google.es")
     print page.http_status
```

And the traceback now is :

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'http_status' but if I use the same code without the

> print page.http_status

It shows no error

EDIT2:

Martijn Pieters give me this possible solution :

```
from ghost import Ghost, Session

ghost = Ghost()

ghost = Session(ghost)

ghost.open('http://www.google.com')

ghost.capture_to('screen_shot.png')
```

This code works but the screenshot is empty and the object has a 'none' type

Comment: Interestingly enough, I can't find an `open()` method, looks like the project refactored but forgot to update the quickstart.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py/issues/304, there may be others in their issue tracker.

Comment: What I obtain with this is an empty screenshot. I'm obtaining "None" for the "page" object

Answer (score 2):

```
from ghost import Ghost
ghost = Ghost()

with ghost.start() as session:
    page, extra_resources = session.open("http://www.google.de")
    session.set_viewport_size(1920,1080)
    session.capture_to('test.png')
~
```

~